# How to combine different jsp pages into one without ajax

Tags: java, jsp, web

I'm developing a web site with different pages that share some common parts, like the menu, the header and the footer.

So what i want to do is write these common component just once and combine them into one single page.

So far I'm doing something that I'm sure that's not the best way to do so: I'm generating the jsp file without the header, the menu and the footer (just with some blank divs that are going to host those components), and once the page is loaded by the browser I retrieve with ajax each single shared component. But doing this is not so optimised because it forces the browser to run several HTTP requests just to load one single page...

Do you know guys which is the best way to do so? Like a way to combine different jsp pages into a single one (on the server side, avoiding all those ajax calls). I'm thinking about some kind of skeleton used by all the pages that help me to build them ...

I really hope to have made myself clear

Thank you very much for you time, you/we are the best community ever!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can have instead a main jsp file and separate different parts of the page in separate jsp files and you can include those in your main jsp file as such (this is just an example, but you can go crazy with how to split the page).

*main.jsp*

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>

<%@ include file="body.jsp" %>

<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

And you not longer need the Ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

In each of JSP files, include header, menu and footer like this,

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>
<!--
Your JSP page content
-->
<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

This way, if you want to change anything in header/menu/footer, it will be in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I found also this solution:

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>
```

But you have to pay attention because these two solutions have different behaviours.
The following one

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
```

injects the contents of the named file into the JSP containing the tag, as if it were copied and pasted. This is done before the content of the included file is parsed.
The second one behave differently

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>
```

the result of rendering the specified page is injected into the containing JSP at the point of the tag. This is done by essentially submitting the requested page to the same container, as a separate rendering request, and taking the results, not the content of the file.

To know something more about it [read this](https://objectpartners.com/2011/04/14/jsp-to-include-or-jspinclude/), that actually is the resource where these information come from